# Pandas - adding new date column based on parsing other date column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, parsing

I am trying to take a Pandas dataframe, parse a column that represents dates and add a new column to the dataframe with a simple mm/dd/yyyy format.

Here is the data and libraries:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

df = pd.DataFrame([['row1', 'Tue Jun 16 19:05:44 UTC 2020', 'record1'], ['row2', 'Tue Jun 16 17:10:02 UTC 2020', 'record2'], ['row3', 'Fri Jun 12 17:52:37 UTC 2020', 'record3']], columns=["row", "checkin", "record"])
```

From picking bits and pieces from around here I crafted this line to parse and add the new column of data:

```
df['NewDate'] = df.apply(lambda row: datetime.date.strftime(parse(df['checkin']), "%m/%d/%Y"), axis = 1)
```

But I end up with this error when run, can anyone suggest a fix or easier way to do this, seems like it should be simpler and more pythonic than I am finding

**TypeError: ('Parser must be a string or character stream, not Series', 'occurred at index 0')**

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Three great answers, thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do so without `apply`

```
df['newDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.checkin).dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

    row                       checkin   record     newDate
0  row1  Tue Jun 16 19:05:44 UTC 2020  record1  06/16/2020
1  row2  Tue Jun 16 17:10:02 UTC 2020  record2  06/16/2020
2  row3  Fri Jun 12 17:52:37 UTC 2020  record3  06/12/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Just  change `df['checkin']` to `row['checkin']`  as below

```
df['NewDate'] = df.apply(lambda row: datetime.date.strftime(parse(row['checkin']), "%m/%d/%Y"), axis = 1)
```

Comment: I like this idea for converting a column of mixed formatted string dates, but I had to drop .date.